# Passing string to file name in R

Tags: r

I have a variable `a=0.01`

Then I create a matrix: `b<-matrix(data=1:5,ncol=5,nrow=1)`

I would now like to save the matrix so that the name of the matrix is the value stored in `a`:

```
save(b_'string', file="b_'string'.Rdata")
```

Where 'string' should be the value stored in `a`, i.e. `0.01`

So the file should be called `b_0.01.Rdata` and the variable stored should be `b_0.01`

Comment: save(b,file=paste0("b_",a,".Rdata"))

Comment: but how about adding 0.01 to the variable name within the file?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new string to feed to `file`, e.g. using `paste0`:

```
save(b,file=paste0("b_",a,".Rdata"))
```

Comment: You should probably either save 'a' as well to the file, or add 'a' as an attribute to matrix 'b' so you know what it meant.